# How can I fix mosquito problem in my garage, sealing garage doors

Tags: pest-control, garage-door

I live in swampy Florida, I get pterodactyls in my garage at night, it's weird too like clockwork at 1am it seems they peak. The garage seems relatively well sealed. Are they getting in through the garage door most likely? I've found prallethin works very well but I hate using chemicals. Would prefer to beef up my sealing. Any recommendations on improving garage door sealing?

Comment: I think it is impossible for a consumer grade overhead garage door to seal well enough to exclude mosquitoes. Just accept them in your garage as another sub-optimal feature of your world. I would not spray permethrin or bifenthrin around the edges of the door. Maybe get some kind of mosquito trap?

Comment: What do they damage in the garage?  If you are working there a small fan(s) will keep them off.

Comment: How about citronella?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what you observed to decide that it's "relatively well sealed".
You can get strips at your local lumber/big box store, which have a built in gasket.  Cut and nail/screw them to the outside frame with gasket slightly compressed against the door.  Do both sides and the top.  That will seal the edges.  If the door bottom doesn't have a gasket, nail a rubber one  on there too.

[Example product](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Frost-King-E-O-3-in-x-108-in-Top-and-Sides-Vinyl-Garage-Door-Weather-Strip-GR9/100185922)

That should take care of the door, but my garage is also vented via the soffits, so small flying insects will always find their way in.  If you have them in large numbers, investigate their ingress and any attractants you may have.